# When I enter a breakpoint for a puts() function, why is GDB not allowing me to enter the input?

Tags: c, security, debugging, gdb, buffer-overflow

I need to enter user input as I am investigating potential buffer overflow vulnerability. I have set a breakpoint and the program asks for user input, however gdb seems to skip over this. For example, when I try to enter the user input, gdb says it's not a command.

I have used gdb to debug my program. I have set a breakpoint to a memory address  by using `break *0x080486a6` however the gdb still seems to skip this and doesn't allow me to enter user input. I have used the `step`, `c` and `next` command to go through the breakpoints.

I used `disass main` to get information about the program which shows:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:                         
   0x0804865d <+0>:     lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx                     
   0x08048661 <+4>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp                   
   0x08048664 <+7>:     pushl  -0x4(%ecx)                         
   0x08048667 <+10>:    push   %ebp                               
   0x08048668 <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp                          
   0x0804866a <+13>:    push   %ecx                               
   0x0804866b <+14>:    sub    $0x14,%esp                         
   0x0804866e <+17>:    mov    0x804a03c,%eax                     
   0x08048673 <+22>:    push   $0x0                               
   0x08048675 <+24>:    push   $0x2                               
   0x08048677 <+26>:    push   $0x0                               
   0x08048679 <+28>:    push   %eax                               
   0x0804867a <+29>:    call   0x8048490 <setvbuf@plt>            
   0x0804867f <+34>:    add    $0x10,%esp                         
   0x08048682 <+37>:    call   0x8048450 <getegid@plt>            
   0x08048687 <+42>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)                    
   0x0804868a <+45>:    sub    $0x4,%esp                          
   0x0804868d <+48>:    pushl  -0xc(%ebp)                         
   0x08048690 <+51>:    pushl  -0xc(%ebp)                         
   0x08048693 <+54>:    pushl  -0xc(%ebp)                         
   0x08048696 <+57>:    call   0x80484b0 <setresgid@plt>          
   0x0804869b <+62>:    add    $0x10,%esp                         
   0x0804869e <+65>:    sub    $0xc,%esp                          
   0x080486a1 <+68>:    push   $0x8048810                         
   0x080486a6 <+73>:    call   0x8048460 <puts@plt>               
   0x080486ab <+78>:    add    $0x10,%esp                         
   0x080486ae <+81>:    call   0x804862f <vuln>                   
   0x080486b3 <+86>:    mov    $0x0,%eax                          
   0x080486b8 <+91>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx                    
   0x080486bb <+94>:    leave                                     
   0x080486bc <+95>:    lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
```

I put a breakpoint on `0x080486a6` and the addresses that are before and after this function. This is what the gdb shows which doesn't allow me to input information:

```
Breakpoint 4, 0x080486a6 in main ()                               
(gdb) c                                                           
Continuing.                                                       
Please enter your string:                                         

Breakpoint 5, 0x080486ab in main () 
(gdb)
```

I expect to be able to input data when the gdb asks me to enter a string. The actual result is that it does not allow me to do this and skips to the next gdb command.

UPDATE: It's now working when I restart the program and it does break on the puts function and this asks for user input (see example below)

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x080486a6 in main ()                                                       
(gdb) c                                                                                   
Continuing.                                                                               
Please enter your string:                                                                 
test
```

However I still want an answer as to why it would jump over this in the first place. If it was because puts doesn't allow the user to enter input, then why is it now working? I've figured out that this problem occurs if I place a breakpoint directly after `0x080486a6` meaning a breakpoint on the `add` operand at memory address `0x080486ab`and a breakpoint at memory address `0x080486a6` - my question is, why does this cause the problem to occur?

Answer (score 0):

`puts` does not ask for user input. It produces output.

Comment: Please see update as it seems to now be working with the puts function. I want to know why it wasn't in the first instance though.

Comment: @iiiiiii In the first instance, the breakpoint at 0x080486ab was hit, the program was suspended, and gdb gained control of your terminal. The program won't continue until you give gdb another `c` command. After you do that, `vuln` will be called and read your input.